# When InterruptedException thrown from Thread.sleep?

Tags: java

when does the thread.sleep generate InterruptedException? I am using this but exception not occuring.Please help about using threads. about passing information to thread and returning information from thread.
public class myThread extends Thread{

```
@Override
public void run(){

    try{

    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(200);   
        System.out.println("Thread is running");

    }
   }
   catch(InterruptedException ex){
   System.out.println("Exception Occur");
   }
}
```

exception does not occur after 200ms. why??

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: And there's always [the documentation for `InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) which (amongst other things) refers to [`Thread.interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

Comment: You don't pass information to and from *threads*. You pass information to and from *objects*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, InterruptedException is generated when you try to kill/interrupt the thread that is sleeping.

Answer (score 4):

`InterruptedException` is thrown in response to `Thread.interrupt` being invoked on the `Thread` instance managing the thread in which you call `sleep`. You can easily test it by calling that method yourself, even within the same thread where you call `sleep`. Just precede that call with `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` and see what happens.